# Trouble with Twilio / TwiML statusCallback using Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, twilio

When a user texts my number, I would like to respond with a message using TwiML. I'd also like to know whether my response message sends or fails. I'm creating my TwiML response using the Twilio library for Node.js.

Here is my code:

```
const response = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
response.message(Response, {
  statusCallback: '/sms/status/'
});
```

Here is the code for the route. Please note that the router is mounted upon the "/sms/" router:

```
router.post('/status/', acceptRequestsOnlyFromTwilio, (req, res) => {
    const Event = require('./../models/schemas/event');
    const event = new Event({
        description:
            `MessageSid = ${req.body.MessageSid}
            MessageStatus = ${req.body.MessageStatus}`
    });
    event.save();
    console.log(
        `MessageSid = ${req.body.MessageSid}
        MessageStatus = ${req.body.MessageStatus}`
    );
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

When I check my logs using the Heroku CLI, I don't log nor do I see a record when I check MongoDB.

Anyone have any ideas or tips on how I can go about debugging this or if I'm implementing this incorrectly?

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Firstly, have you set your Messaging request URL for the Twilio phone number you are using? Is it pointing at the correct route for your Message TwiML response?

[image: fill in the Messaging section "Request URL" field with your URL.]

Also, your first code block should also be within a `router.post` endpoint for your server. Do you correctly return the TwiML response as the server response?

As a tip, it might be better to develop this application locally and test your webhook endpoints using a tool like [ngrok](http://ngrok.com). [I love using ngrok to test webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

Comment: Thanks for the ngrok tip--I'll check it out. The first code block is from a middleware function that generates my TwiML response. I have a TwiML app associated with my test number that has the correct URL for my server endpoint that returns a TwiML response. I believe that it's correct because I receive the expected response message on my phone. What does not seem to be working is the statusCallback. I'm not sure how to tell whether it's being called or if it's throwing an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any logs for the request hitting `/sms/status/` on your server at all? Do you use the `acceptRequestsOnlyFromTwilio` function for other parts of the application that are working correctly?

Comment: acceptRequestsOnlyFromTwilio works correctly for other routes and the statusCallback still doesn't work if I remove it. I don't see any logs for the request hitting /sms/status. Is there a way to see if Twilio is ever even attempting to POST to it? How can I debug this using Twilio's tools?

Comment: I haven't used status callbacks for messages before, but I will have a play with this and let you know what I find out.

Comment: Any luck? My status callback URL isn't being posted to even when I use the Twilio client to send a message. Could the issue be that I'm using a trial account?